# TableRow.FindControl(cell.ID) returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

why doesn't the cell i just added to a row get found with FindControl()?

```
// cell
var cell = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell();
cell.ID = "cell";

// cell in row
var row = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow();
row.Controls.Add(cell);

// get cell from row
var foundCell = row.FindControl(cell.ID);
```

foundCell becomes null

Comment: are you able to see the cell in row array in debug mode?

Comment: pass whole cell to FindControl function. Like this: var foundCell = row.FindControl(cell)

Comment: Did you check the collection of `Controls`? Is the `Cell` item added correctly? And try to remove `row` before `FindControl`

Comment: @Keppy i can see the cell in row.Controls and in row.Cells in debug mode, both with the ID i gave it

Comment: @MajkeloDev var foundCell = row.FindControl(cell); doesn't compile. and in the actual situation i don't have the reference to the cell anymore

Comment: i know this is a simple question, but for the down votes, i would have expected some better answers. don't be ignorant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `FindControl` a **dynamic** item that created from back-end programming code, asp.net need to post_back to add the Control to DOM.

In your case, you need to separate your Adding Control function and Finding Control function in different asp.net life-cycle.

First, Create the Control in `Page_Init`:

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // cell
    var cell = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell();
    cell.ID = "cell";

    // cell in row
    var row = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow();
    row.Controls.Add(cell);
}
```

Then you can find the Control in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get cell from row
    var foundCell = Page.FindControl("cell"); // or you can store the cell Id in a string variable
}
```

You can find more info on MSDN, on the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) article.

Comment: thanks that was it. although i don't see anything in that link about this behavior. i didn't expect this to have anything to do with the page life cycle

Comment: @symbiont Page_Init will load before Page_Load :)

Comment: the strange thing is that Page.FindControl() seems to always work regardless. for example when adding and finding the control in Page_Load(). so it looks like it's something else. but at least i have a solution now

Answer (score 0):

`row.findControl(cell.ID)` is not working in your case and you can replace it with below logic and its working fine.

```
var foundCell = row.Cells[row.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell)];
```